# Should posts to DataScience contain only one question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97138/what-can-we-learn-from-pca-on-non-linear-data) contains 3 questions as it’s currently written. I know that StackOverflow and GIS.stackexchange require one question per post. Does the same standard apply to DataScience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the same standard apply to DataScience?

Yes.